# peculiar Java 7 Web Start failure

Tags: java

I maintain a legacy application that was written with the Java 6 JDK.  We deploy it as a stand alone application downloaded from the web as a JNLP.  The application talks to a servlet that serves up data from a database, and since the data involved can get lengthy, the JNLP app provides a 'progress meter' to show how much data has transferred and how much is left to go.  It was working all just fine - until, apparently, the latest Java 7 update.  Now, when the JNLP application is run, during data transfer from the servlet, the progress meter stops working.  It appears to get hung, yet data is continuing to be transferred (the servlet part is working just fine).  But to our end users, the app appears to fail!  I can run the app locally without Webstart, and it works fine.  Any idea what the problem could be, and how to fix it?.

Comment: Which Java version? Did you try the latest update?

Comment: Do you use a SwingWorker to load the data in a background thread and update progress bar in the EDT?

Comment: Java 1.7 update 9 and 10 appear to fail the same way.  And yes, a SwingWorker is used to load the data and update progress.